# SQL: How to refer to multiple data sets with only one id?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, primary-key

I want to create a table "orders" which holds orders. It shall have fields including the userID and the orderID. In another table, called "orderItems", I want to list all items which refer to one order. The problem is, that all items, which refer to one order, should be queried by only one ID. Because it would be possible to only set this ID in the orderID field of "orders".

So, how do I have to create the indexes? Is it possible to realize it in that way? Do you have suggestions how to improve this scheme?

I hope you understand, what I was trying to tell you.

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is best solved with a foreign key between the `Order` and `OrderItems` table that uses the `ORDER_ID` column.

There is no way to use the `ORDER_ID` as the primary key for each `ORDER_ITEM` since the key would not be unique.

**DDL**

```
create table `order`(
    order_id int NOT NULL,
    customer_name varchar(50),
    primary key(order_id)
);

create table order_item(
  order_item_id int NOT NULL,
  order_id int,
  item_name varchar(50),
  primary key(order_item_id),
  foreign key(order_id) references `order`(order_id)
);
```

Once you have this DDL setup you can easily reference an order using one key by joining the two tables.

```
select * from
`order` o
join order_item oi
on o.order_id = oi.order_id
where o.order_id = 5;
```